# php automated setter and getter

Tags: php, oop, setter, getter

I'm trying to implement some automated getter and setter for php objects.

My target is to automatically have for each properties the methods `getProperty()` and `setProperty(value)`, that way if the method is not implemented for a property the script will  simply set or get the value.

An example, to make myself clear:

```
class Foo {
    public $Bar;
}

$A = new A();
$A->setBar("bar");
$A->getBar(); // -> output "bar"
```

or

```
class Foo {
    public $Bar;
    public function setBar($bar) { $Bar = $bar; }
    public function getBar($bar) { return 'the value is: ' . $bar; }
}

$A = new A();
$A->setBar("bar");
$A->getBar(); // -> output "the value is: bar"
```

Any idea/hints on how to accomplish this?

Comment: just a shot in the field: How about you parse the document and write setters and getters with an output writer for every found property. I'd further recommend to search for Frameworks who already can do this. <offtopic>Other Platforms can do it even with automated persistance (e.g. Grails for the Java Platform)</offtopic>

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to simulate the `getXy` and `setXy` functions for arbitrary properties, then use the magic [`__call`](http://php.net/__call) wrapper:

```
function __call($method, $params) {

     $var = lcfirst(substr($method, 3));

     if (strncasecmp($method, "get", 3) === 0) {
         return $this->$var;
     }
     if (strncasecmp($method, "set", 3) === 0) {
         $this->$var = $params[0];
     }
}
```

This would be a good opportunity to do something useful for once, by adding a typemap or anything. Otherwise eschewing [getters and setters](https://web.archive.org/web/20120411001400/http://berryllium.nl/2011/02/getters-and-setters-evil-or-necessary-evil/) alltogether might be advisable.

Comment: a couple of fixes
    `strncasecmp($method, "set", 3) === 0 // same thing for the prev`
and
    `$var = lcfirst(substr($method, 3)); // e.g. for camelcase`

Comment: @th3n3rd Your link is dead

Comment: @turibe I didn't post any link, I am not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: @th3n3rd That comment was meant for me/the answer (and linky link fixed: internat-archive et al.)

Answer (score 3):

read the `magic functions of php` and your need you can use `__get and __set` functions

[read this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members)

Comment: that's not it. I need the trick the other way around. `__get` and `__set` are used when the property itself doesn't exist

Comment: He did tell you to read about magic functions. Check what `__call` magic function does.